# SQL finding multiple users using the same account

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE actions
 userID INT not NULL,
 deviceIP VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
 action VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,,
 actionTimestamp timestamp NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (userID )
}
```

How can I write an sql that selects all rows of users using different IP's at the same time +- 60 seconds ?

`SELECT * FROM actions WHERE ??`

For Example for the following data

```
userID|actionTimestamp              | deviceIP        | action 
67    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 11.11.11.111    | a1
67    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 11.11.11.111    | a2
67    | 2021-07-27 21:21:48.340605  | 22.22.22.222    | a1
70    | 2021-07-27 21:21:38.340605  | 33.33.33.333    | a3
70    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 33.33.33.333    | a4
71    | 2021-07-27 21:22:28.340605  | 55.55.55.555    | a5
71    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 44.44.44.444    | a6
71    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 44.44.44.444    | a7
```

Expected result is

```
 userID|actionTimestamp              |deviceIP         | action 
 67    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 11.11.11.111    | a1
 67    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 11.11.11.111    | a2
 67    | 2021-07-27 21:21:48.340605  | 22.22.22.222    | a1
 71    | 2021-07-27 21:22:28.340605  | 55.55.55.555    | a5
 71    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 44.44.44.444    | a6 
 71    | 2021-07-27 21:21:08.340605  | 44.44.44.444    | a7
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear.  What is an account?  What results do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated the question with sample data

Comment: Why is userID=71 in your expected results?

Comment: @forpas because at the same time  (+-) 60 seconds he is taking actions from different IP's look at a5 <--> (a6&a7)

Comment: The difference between a5 and the others is more than 60 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Using exists logic, we can return any record for which we can find a *different* record (indicated by a different action timestamp) for the *same* user, such that the two actions were within 60 seconds of each other.

```
SELECT a1.*
FROM actions a1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM actions a2
              WHERE a2.userID = a1.userID AND
                    a2.actionTimestamp != a1.actionTimestamp AND
                    ABS(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (a2.actionTimestamp - a1.actionTimestamp))) <= 60);
```

Comment: Thank for the sql, it doesn't show the result I'm expecting - Iv'e updated the question with an example and sample data

Answer (score 0):

If you want users that are using different ips within a two minute span, you can use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from actions a
where exists (select 1
              from actions a2
              where a2.userId = a.userId and
                    a2.deviceIP <> a.deviceIP and
                    a2.timestamp > a.timetamp - interval '60 second' and
                    a2.timestamp < a.timestamp + interval '60 second'
             )
order by userid, timestamp;
```

Note:  This only provides the rows within the two minute interval, which is how I interpret your question (as opposed to "all rows for all times").

EDIT:

If you want *all* the rows for an ip that has this occurring at least once, I would suggest window functions:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_timestamp > timestamp - interval '60 second' and prev_deviceip <> deviceip) as cnt_multis
      from (select a.*,
                   lag(timestamp) over (partition by userid order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp,
                   lag(deviceip) over (partition by userid order by timestamp) as prev_deviceip
            from actions a
           ) a
     ) a
where count_multis > 0;
```

Your condition is equivalent to stating that two "adjacent" rows for the same user (by timestamp) have different ips.  If this is the case, than select all rows for that `userid`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for user IDs that are being used by more than one IP.

One way to achieve this:

```
select *
from actions a
where exists
(
  select null 
  from actions a2
  where a2.deviceip = a.deviceip
  and a2.userid <> a.userid
)
order by userid, actiontimestamp;
```

Another:

```
select userid, actiontimestamp, deviceip, action
from
(
  select 
    a.*,
    count(distinct userid) over (partition by deviceip) as user_count
  from actions a
)
where user_count > 1
order by userid, actiontimestamp;
```

Yet another:

```
select *
from actions
where userid in
(
  select userid 
  from actions
  group by userid
  having min(deviceip) <> max(deviceip)
)
order by userid, actiontimestamp;
```